# If a table has columns equal to columns in a second table insert values in a third table, python - mysql

Tags: python, mysql, while-loop, foreign-keys, insertion

I have 3 table in my database:

- Borrowers: amount of the loan, interest rate, borrower id (PK)
- Lenders: amount of the bid, interest rate and LenderID (PK)
- Contracts: ContractID PK, amount, interest rate and the two foreign key(borrowerID, lenderID)

I create a loop in python with an input command in which I can insert new request of loan and new bid offer.
Every insertion is connected with mysql and it is added to the respective table.

For example:

**input in python --> L 1000 1.1 output --> create an insertion in Borrowers table with an auto_incremental PK, an amount of 1000 and an interest rate of 1.1%**

I need to create another function in the loop in which, for every new *request/offer*, if an offer is equal to a request (`Borrowers.Amount, BorrowersInterestRate = Lenders.Amount, Lenders.InterestRate`), it will be created an insertion in contracts table with the same amount and interest rate.

Comment: So what is your problem? Did you try to create? Show your code first please. And describe the problem if will not work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only works if you are using mysql python connector. As far as I know that is the only way to use mysql using python but I maybe wrong.

to search if request matches the offer:

```
def search_for_request(amount, interest_rate):
    # assuming that columns containing amount and interest rate are named as such
    database.cursor.execute("select amount_of_the_bid, interest_rate from lenders")
    result = database.cursor.fetchall()
    for amount_and_interest in result:
        # not sure if this step is necessary
        amount_and_interest = list(amount_and_interest)
        if amount_and_interst[0] == amount and amount_and_interst[1] == interest_rate:
            # execute query for entering the contract info in contract table
            database.commit()
```

to search if offer matches request:

```
def search_for_offer(amount, interest_rate):
    # assuming that columns containing amount and interest rate are named as such
    database.cursor.execute("select amount_of_the_bid, interest_rate from borrowers")
    result = database.cursor.fetchall()
    for amount_and_interest in result:
        # not sure if this step is necessary
        amount_and_interest = list(amount_and_interest)
        if amount_and_interest[0] == amount and amount_and_interest[1] == interest_rate:
            # execute query for entering the contract info in contract table
            database.commit()
```

Comment: It is almost the answer that I was looking for, but thanks to you I understood how to solve my request!